# add label:after after input element

Tags: html, css

I make custom radio checkbox this is my codes:

HTML:

```css
.radio-custom input[type="radio"]:checked + label:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 10.5px;
  margin-top: -5px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 11px;
  line-height: 1;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: #117efd;
  border-radius: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="radio-custom">
     <input type="radio" name="test" id="test" value="test" />
     <label>Test</label>
</div>
```

The problem that if I add any element after`<input type="radio" name="test" id="test" value="test"  />` `label:after` will not get what can to do to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `+` to a `~` and that will do the trick.

The reason yours didn't work is because you were using `+`, which is the adjacent selector or next-sibling selector. Changing it to the general sibling selector `~` will match the second element only if it's preceded by the first and both have the same parent.

```css
.radio-custom input[type="radio"]:checked ~ label:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 10.5px;
  margin-top: -5px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 11px;
  line-height: 1;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: #117efd;
  border-radius: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="radio-custom">
  <input type="radio" name="test" id="test" value="test" />
  <span></span>
  <label>Test</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow this structure:

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 25px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  font-size: 13px;
}
input[type=radio] {
  display: none;
}
label:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
 
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
 
  margin-right: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 1px;
  background-color: #aaa;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
}
.radio label:before {
  border-radius: 8px;
}
input[type=radio]:checked + label:before {
    content: "\2022";
    color: #f3f3f3;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div class="radio">
  <input id="male" type="radio" name="gender" value="male">
  <label for="male">Male</label>
  <input id="female" type="radio" name="gender" value="female">
  <label for="female">Female</label>
</div>
```